# Difficulty understanding RubyMonk exercise called "Whodunnit" involving superclasses

Tags: ruby, while-loop, superclass

I'm trying to understand a solution to a RubyMonk exercise. I can follow most of the code but not the following line,

`while not (superclass = klass.superclass).nil?`

is this creating a variable called 'superclass' to use in the rest of the 'while not loop', and then testing it as != nil, at the same time?

**Full solution**

```
def location_in_hierarchy(object, method)
  klass = object.class
  ancestors = [klass]
  while not (superclass = klass.superclass).nil?
    ancestors << superclass
    klass = superclass
  end
  ancestors.reverse.find do |ancestor| 
    ancestor.instance_methods.include?(method)
  end
end
```

[link to exercize](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/problems/85-whodunnit#solution4016)

I've learned Ruby for a couple weeks now. But I've been starring at this solution for the last hour. Any help understanding this line would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this creating a variable called 'superclass' to use in the rest of
>   the 'while not loop', and then testing it as != nil, at the same time?

Yes. The `(blahblah).nil?` is the loop condition, while the value of `superclass` is used within each iteration.

```
while not (superclass = klass.superclass).nil?
```

It's simply a way of going over all the parent classes (*ancestors*) of `object`. The loop will run until `superclass == BasicObject` (i.e. `klass.superclass == nil`), and in each iteration the name of each superclass is pushed into `ancestors`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a test in irb. if object is 'a':

```
irb(main):009:0> 'a'.class
=> String
irb(main):010:0> 'a'.class.superclass
=> Object
irb(main):011:0> Object.superclass
=> BasicObject
irb(main):013:0> BasicObject.superclass
=> nil
```

so if `klass.superclass` is nil(`klass` is nil), the loop will end.

```
  while not (superclass = klass.superclass).nil?
    ancestors << superclass
    klass = superclass
  end
```

you can understand it like this:

```
   superclass = klass.superclass
   while not superclass.nil?
    ancestors << superclass
    klass = superclass
    superclass = klass.superclass
  end
```

As you say, it create a variable called 'superclass', then check it whether it is nil, if it is nil, the while() loop ends，or assign `klass.superclass`to it.